# multiple errors while executing a jsp project

Tags: java, jsp

I wrote a jsp project, tried to execute it. I got this error:

> listType cannot be resolved to a variable

So I added this lines to my jsp file:

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
```

But it didn't fix the problem. How can I fix it?
There is one more error like this:

> The method StudentDetails() is undefined for the type
>   MangeUser Student.jsp

Here is Student.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="com.junos.users.MangeUser"%>
  <%--   <%@ page import="com.junos.userdetails.UserEntityDetails"%> --%>
    <%@include file="menu.jsp" %>
    <%@page language="java" import="java.util.*,java.io.*,java.sql.*"%>

 <%!int skillLevel_id=0;%>
<jsp:useBean id="Student" class="com.junos.users.MangeUser" />
<jsp:setProperty name="Student" property="*" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title> Users </title>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/data-tables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/data-tables/js/jquery.dataTables.js" />"type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" />"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bootstrap-select:not([class*="col-"]):not([class*="form-control"]):not(.input-group-btn) {
            width: 218px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#usrTable').DataTable();

            $('#UserDiv').hide();
            $('#tblsDiv').hide();
            $('#challenegrDescriptionDiv , #Image ').hide();



            $('#addUser').click(function(){
                $('#UserDiv').show();
                $('#usrTbl').hide();
            });

            $('.cncl').click(function(){
                $('#usrTbl').show();
                $('#UserDiv').hide();
            });
        });

        var roleValue = function(){
            var val = $('#userRole_id option:selected').text();
            if(val == "WAITER"){
                $('#tblsDiv').show();
            }else{
                $('#tblsDiv').hide();
            }

            if(val == "CHALLENGER"){
                $('#usrnmDiv , #passDiv , #cnfrmPassDiv').hide();
            }else{
                $('#usrnmDiv , #passDiv , #cnfrmPassDiv').show();
            }

            if(val == "CHALLENGER"){
                $(' #Image , #description').show();
                $('#challenegrDescriptionDiv , #Image ').show();

            }else{
                $(' #Image , #description').hide();
                $('#challenegrDescriptionDiv , #Image ').hide();

            }


        }   
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function PreviewImage() {
        alert("PreviewImage");
        var oFReader = new FileReader();

        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("profileImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("imagePreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };
    };

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //getting value of radio button      
          $(document).ready(function(){

              $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){

                  var radioValue = $("input[name='name']:checked").val();
                  if(radioValue){

                      alert("Your are a - " + radioValue); 
                  }
                  window.location='EditList.jsp?radioValue='+radioValue;
              });


     });
        </script>

</head>
<body >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="UserDiv" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="usrTbl" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="btn-group" style= "margin-bottom: 10px;">

                <button id="addUser" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn" style="background-color: #9933CC; color: white;margin-left: 10px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <table id="usrTable" class="display text-center table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center">User Name</th>  
                        <th class="text-center">Password</th>  
                        <th class="text-center">Mobile Number</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Email Id</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Challenger Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <%
                    List<MangeUser> userList= Student.StudentDetails();
                        System.out.println("userList  size: " + userList.size());
                        pageContext.setAttribute("Users", userList);

                    %>
                    <c:forEach items="${Users}" var="user">
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.lastName}"/></td>
                         <td><c:out value="${user.username}"/></td>  
                         <td><c:out value="${user.password}"/></td> 
                        <td><c:out value="${user.mobileNumber}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.emailID}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.challengerDescription}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix those 2 errors?

Comment: listType can not be resolved doesn't mean he can't find the type, it means it can't find a declaration of that specific variable.
Start with getting all of that Java code out of your jsp (where it shouldn't be at all) and move it into a servlet.

Comment: Could you attach the class that has method `StudentDetails()`

Comment: Is `StudentDetails()` method a static method?

Comment: @RahulYadav: he's not calling it from a class, he's calling it from within the jsp, where it doesn't seem to exist. Both error messages are quite self-explanatory

Comment: Be aware how you declare methods in jsp.. [HowTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html)

Comment: Include the class which is having the method `StudentDetails()`

Comment: @Stultuske: I'm aware he is calling it from jsp, but I just need to check if the class has that method present.

Comment: @RahulYadav: I meant, he is calling a StudentDetails method that should exist within the jsp file, which doesn't.

Comment: @Stultuske: How can I fix 1st error? Importing required classes into jsp won't help???

Comment: Please check these lines: `<jsp:useBean id="Student" class="com.junos.users.MangeUser" />` and 
`<jsp:setProperty name="Student" property="*" />`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni: by declaring variables before you try to use them. My recommendation: learn basic Java before trying to create webapplications